# How to concatenate text_fields values before save in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 text fields:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:image1, nil, :placeholder => "Ссылка на фото тут") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:image2, nil, :placeholder => "Ссылка на фото тут") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:image3, nil, :placeholder => "Ссылка на фото тут") %>

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
end


def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category, :post_type, :image)
end
```

So, I want to concatenate these 3 text fields(:image1, :image2, :image3) in :image before save. How can I do it?

Concatenate by "_"

**UPDATE**

form code: http://pastebin.com/HTBTJtnQ
post controller: http://pastebin.com/NF2MEyrg

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you can do this

```
def create
    post_params[:image] = params[:image1].to_s + "_" + params[:image2].to_s + "_" + params[:image3].to_s
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
end
```

Comment: it wrote "NULL" in database

Answer (score 0):

Strong params also behaves like Hash, if I recall correctly. If that's the case, 
then `post_params.values_at(:image1, :image_2, :image_3).join(' ')` should work (see Hash#values_at). But you need to allow those three first; now you only allow `:image`.

Answer (score 0):

from this

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category, :post_type, :image)
end
```

to this

```
def post_params
    params[:image] = params[:image1].to_s + "_" + params[:image2].to_s + "_" + params[:image3].to_s
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category, :post_type, :image)
end
```

Comment: this is a simple way, but it gives you an idea of what you need to change. i don't like modifying the params, usually when i do this i use another variable to substitute it.

Answer (score 0):

If your textfield are in your view, you need to allow them in your post_param function :

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category, :post_type,
  :image1,:image2,:image3)
end
```

Then, in create,

```
def create
   image =  post_params[:image1]+"_"+post_params[:image2]+"_"+post_params[:image3]
   good_param = post_param #so you can modify the param's values
   good_param[:image] = image
   #delete image1,2,3 from good_param
   @post = Post.new(good_param)
end
```

Should do the work

Answer (score 0):

To have a concatenation take place before the save, you can do this in your `Post` model:

```
before_save :concatenate_images

def concatenate_images
  self.[your field name] = [array of params].join('_')
  self.save
end
```